# post multiple select dropdown generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, codeigniter, post, dynamic-arrays

i have a simple **script** in my codeigniter view that when i click a button add a  dinamically with a 2 text field and a multiple dropdown select

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[]">
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname[]">
<select name="food[]" multiple>
    <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
    <option value="2">Lunch</option>
    <option value="3">Dinner</option>
    <option value="4">Snacks</option>
    <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

now when i post all variables from view to controller for the text field i havent problem

```
[name] => Array
    (
        [0] => name1
        [1] => name2
    )
[surname] => Array
    (
        [0] => surname1
        [1] => surname2
    )
[food] => Array
    (
        [0] => Lunch
        [1] => Dinner
        [2] => Dessert
        [3] => Dinner
        [4] => Lunch
    )
```

i have problem with the multiple select(food) because i dont know about the index of the array

i know tha at the index [0] there are name1 and surname1 of the first row but with multiple selection of the select what is the correct index ?
anyone can help me ? there is a way to store the correct value of food ? example

**name1 surname1 Lunch,Dinner,Dessert**

**name2 surname2 Dinner,Lunch**

sorry for the english

Comment: show us in picture format what exactly you want??

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop your foodlist.

**My controller:**

```
public function create()
{
    $food_list = $this->input->post('food');
   
    foreach($food_list as $food) {
    
       $data= array(
        'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
        'surname' => $this->input->post('surname'),
        'food' => $food
    );
    $this->db->insert('table_name', $data);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply @KUMAR
my problem is that in the view i add section with javascript
With name and surname no problem because are a single data
but with food the index increase each food that i select

example first row
name:john surname:doe food:breakfast,lunch
name:carl surname:brave food:dinner,snacks

the resultant array are
name[0] john name[1] carl
surname[0] doe surname[1] brave
food[0]breakfast food[1]lunch food[1]dinner food[1]snacks

i would that at index 0 this information john doe breakfast lunch
at index 1 carl brave dinner snacks
thanks if you are understand

Answer (score 0):

Current:-

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[]">
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname[]">
<select name="food[]" multiple>
  <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
  <option value="2">Lunch</option>
  <option value="3">Dinner</option>
  <option value="4">Snacks</option>
  <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

Try Grouping the input names to get your desired output:-

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name[1][]">
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname[1][]">
<select name="food[1][]" multiple>
   <option value="1">Breakfast</option>
   <option value="2">Lunch</option>
   <option value="3">Dinner</option>
   <option value="4">Snacks</option>
   <option value="5">Dessert</option>
</select>
```

Refer [this](https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/) it may help you in grouping input values

Comment: maybe food[1] must change in something like a $index but this is automatic create without index only in javascript have you any solutions ?

Comment: @riccardoairone you can set javascript variable as a counter and while inserting inputs you can use them for index